# String to DateTime in Python Correct Format error

Tags: python, datetime

I know this question is out there quite a bit, but I cannot find a solution for my case. I have a DataFrame with a column Time in string format that I need to convert to datetime. Ultimately, I want the date as an int for ML purposes, but I cannot seem to get it to datetime first.

I have:

```
testDate = tripOrig[' Time'][0]
newDate = dt.datetime.strptime(testDate,'%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')
```

Where the dates are strings like:

```
05-Jun-2016 00:00:00.000 EDT
```

For whatever reason, I keep getting the error that it is in the wrong format. I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. I checked the datetime docs over many times but I keep getting:

```
ValueError: time data '05-Jun-2016 00:00:00.000 EDT' does not match format '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'
```

What am I missing here?!?

As another note, I have also tried:

```
tripOrig['correct date'] = pd.to_datetime(tripOrig[' Time'])
```

This is very slow, throws a timezone warning, and does not account for seconds when convert to int, so I cannot use it.

How can I get this converted?

Comment: the issue is with `EDT` it's not recognized, swap it with `UTC` and the code snippet works fine. You need to see the equivalent time zone for EDT recognized by datetime.

Comment: According to this page: https://rdrr.io/r/base/strptime.html. `%Z` is output only.

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673614/10197418

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python strptime() and timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305413/python-strptime-and-timezones)

Comment: another potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67875823/10197418

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a couple other questions, I found my solution:

[Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63184876/parser-must-be-a-string-or-character-stream-not-series)

[how to convert a string datetime with unknown timezone to timestamp in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206500/how-to-convert-a-string-datetime-with-unknown-timezone-to-timestamp-in-python)

From string to Posix/Unix int:

```
import datetime as dt
from time import mktime
from dateutil import parser

def timeCorrect(stringDate):
    stamp = parser.parse(stringDate, tzinfos={"EDT": -4 * 3600})
    work = mktime(stamp.timetuple())
    return work
        
tripOrig['Correct Time'] =  tripOrig[' Time'].apply(timeCorrect)
```